# How to display image from database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

I have saved image in database and wanna show it in asp.net ,I have byte array and MIME and size...

```
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetBlob", sqlConnection);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlobId", blobDto.BlobId);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "GetBlob");
                var dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                var byteArray = (byte[]) dr["BlobData"];
                string MIME=dr["MIME"]; e.g .jpg
```

Please help me how can I show this image

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your byte array to base64 encoded string and pass it to some `img` tag as `src` attribute. The `src` attribute format for base64 encoded image is -   **data:*conentType*;base64,*theBase64string***.

To convert a byte array to base64 string use Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

Example C#:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ }; // .. Get it from database
string contentType = "image/jpeg"; // .. Get it from database

string imageSrc = string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", 
    contentType, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

In Html:

```
<img src="@imageSrc" />
// Or
<img src="<%= imageSrc =>" />
// Depending on your view engine
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work correctly, actually it shows nothing !!

Comment: It works as I described. If it doesn't work for you the problem is somewhere in your code. Please share more of your code and tell what exact technology you use so I can make more complete example. For now here is [dotnetfiidle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hksAY2) for ASP.NET MVC.