# Displaying Image from Database to an Image Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

```
private void MovieDisp1()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = CinemaProj; Integrated Security = SSPI");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select CM_MovieName, CM_MovieDesc, CM_MovieImage from Tbl_CMovies where CM_ID = '1'";
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        labelmoviename1.Text = rd[0].ToString();
        labelmoviedesc1.Text = rd[1].ToString();
        byte[] img = (byte[])(rd[2]);
        if(img == null)
        {
            ImageMovie1.Image = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            ImageMovie1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

I've made a method named MovieDisp1 to retrieve all the information from my database including the image. But now I'm having an error at

> ImageMovie1.Image = null

as well as

> ImageMovie1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

The error is this:

**'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Does it mean I can't use .Image for Image Control? Is there any extension method to be used so that I can fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Everything that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface needs to disposed of properly. You have not done so in your code. You either need to wrap them in [using statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) or call `.Dispose()` on them in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to consider is that, the datatype of your Image in database should be VarBinary(MAX).

```
 using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = CinemaProj; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
{
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGE FROM t_TableName WHERE ID=1", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           da.fill(ds);

        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Table[0].Rows)
        {
            imgByte = (byte[])(dr["Image"]);
        }
        string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte);
}
```

//for `<img>` tag use this (imgF is ID of the img TAG):

```
imgF.Src = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
```

//for `<asp:Image>` use this:

```
imgF.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
```

Comment: Everything that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface needs to disposed of properly. You have not done so in your code. You either need to wrap them in [using statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) or call .Dispose() on them in a finally block.

Comment: oh yes, I stand corrected.. I focused too much on the solution to his question... i edited my answer :) thanks sir

Comment: After struggling through many code samples, this worked for me.  Thanks, JC.

Answer (score -1):

Try reading this: [ASP Image Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And this: [Use Byte Array to Create an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binary-data-to-an-image-control-in-asp-net)

And Another: [how-to-display-image-from-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956311/how-to-display-image-from-database-in-asp-net?rq=1)

Rather than trying to convert the Database Image into an Image Object, just fetch the data and store it in a byte[] Array, and use the binary data directly in your images src.

Create your image element:

```
<img runat="server" id="image" />
```

Then just pass that byte array to the image tags .src property. There is more information about that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binary-data-to-an-image-control-in-asp-net)